# How to display custom related posts in bullet form

Tags: php

I am using custom fields plugin for related posts to show related post on my choice. I want to display the related post list in bullet form. but I am stuck here. Please help me. PHP Code for the related posts is

```
<?php  
$posts = get_field('related_posts'); 
if ($posts) { ?>
    <h3 class="related">Related posts</h3>
    <p>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) { setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br/>
    <?php } //End for each loop
    wp_reset_postdata(); //Restores WP post data ?>
    </p>
    <hr />
<?php } //End if ?>
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($posts) { 
?>
    <style>
      ul.related-list {
         list-style-type: circle;
      }
    </style>
    <h3 class="related">Related posts</h3>
    <ul class="related-list">
        <?php 
         foreach($posts as $post) { 
             setup_postdata($post); 
             ?>
             <li>
                <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
             </li>
         <?php 
         } //End for each loop
         ?>
    </ul>
    <hr />
<?php 
wp_reset_postdata(); //Restores WP post data 
} //End if
```

Comment: Thanks Juan for such quick response. But, this code has limited the number of related posts. Now I can see only one related post below the content area. in each page.

Comment: And before my answer you could see them all?

Comment: Yes, but not in bullet style. Now this is neither in bullet style nor showing all the posts.

Comment: the original code is  <?php  
$posts = get_field('related_posts'); 
if ($posts) { ?>
    <h3 class="related">Related posts</h3>
    <p>
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) { setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> &raquo;</a><br/>
    <?php } //End for each loop
    wp_reset_postdata(); //Restores WP post data ?>
    </p>
    <hr />
<?php } //End if ?>

Comment: Wow, That code is unreadable, but anyway. Are you sure is not something related to the CSS? because what I did was change the <p> tag for a <ul>, and the <a> elementes are inside <li> list items. It should have nothing to do with the rest of the logic

Comment: Sorry for troubling you Juan. I wrote php opening tag two times. Now I have rearranged and all the posts are showing above the comment area, but still not in bullet style.

Comment: Seeing that you're using a Wordpress template, we will have to add a class and custom CSS for our Related Posts List. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: . I am totally confused. This is not a tough css coding and you have done absolutely perfect. But still.....

Comment: Even I can see listing codes  <ul> in page source but not on webpage.

Comment: Pretty pretty sure is the CSS. It must contain some "!important" rules and we cannot override them. You must access the template css after inspecting the elements and seeing where the styles come from. We need to check that

Comment: Yes Juan, alignment is included under Generic class.

Comment: Also provide some screenshots or the URL, would be usefull

Comment: Yep, as I suspected, it's a CSS related problem. You need to add a custom class to the CSS file and set the list-style-type to whatever you like the most

Comment: But what would the class. I am adding .related_posts ul {
 margin:0;
 overflow:hidden;
} and getting any change. I will be obliged for your help

Comment: Solved Juan. Thanks for your great help. The class was added already added still we are adding ui code whereas only li was sufficient to convert the related posts list into bullet style. Again thank you so much. You can check   http://www.howto-connect.com/